# Inserting one entity into a new column

Tags: sql

Today is my first day working with SQL so please bear with me for this incredibly simple question.  I have been struggling with this for quite some time now...so any help is greatly appreciated

If I have a table (named Test) filled out and I add one new column, how do I then insert values into ONLY the new column. For example I have a table with 2 colummns (col1, col2).  If I add a third (col3)....how do I insert values [on the same rows I already had] into my new column.

If you can't understand what I am saying...please tell me and I will try to be more concise.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,Use Update query

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET col3 = <value> WHERE col1=<value>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use and UPDATE syntax,

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <colname> = <value> WHERE <whereclause>
```

Comment: WHERE is the criteria for the row(s) you want, it tells the database on which rows to do the statement (i.e. WHERE col1 = 'peanuts' would only apply the update where the first column value under the column named 'col1' was equal to peanuts